# twttr.widgets.load() is not updating the url

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter

I have built a website using backbone, such that the page loads once and all other content is loaded dynamically using ajax. At the bottom of the page I have social media links for FB, LinkedIN, Twitter, and G+. I've been working today to make sure those links are updated as the current url is updated, and while I have it working, twttr.widgets.load() is not behaving properly. Here is my relevant code:

**HTML:**

```
<span id='twitterholder'></span>
<script src='//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js'></script>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    try {
        $('#twitterholder').empty();            // remove the current button
        var t = $("<a href='https://twitter.com/share' class='twitter-share-button'>"); // create a new button
        $(t).attr('data-text', document.title); // set the title
        $(t).attr('data-url', location.href);   // set the url
        $(t).appendTo($('#twitterholder'));     // add the button to the page
        twttr.widgets.load();
    } catch(ex){}
});
```

(Yes, I could set the url and title at the same time as I create the new element, but that's not the point of this question - let's let that slide please) When I do this, the button refreshes - I can watch it happen - but it always does so with the title and url it had before. What am I doing wrong?

**MY WORKAROUND:**

In the meantime, rather than including the script to load widgets.js in the main body of the page, I'm adding it as a second element within my ajaxComplete function. When it loads, it automatically seeks out unloaded twitter buttons, and loads them, and when it happens in this way the buttons have the correct title and url. But reloading the script every time is sloppy, and I'd rather not do that.

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious question, but are the page title and href updated in the ajax function?  And are they both global variables?

Comment: They are. The code works when I reload the entire script, just not when i call the function myself.

Comment: Can you share your ajax function?

Comment: I can, but it's irrelevant: even if I run each line of my `ajaxComplete()` function manually, after the url and title have been changed, I get the same result.